# Maven and cron job

Tags: java, maven, cron

I have a java code in the folder folder1/scripts/appname. I need to get into the folder "appname" and do

```
    mvn clean test -Dhr=1 -Dmin=0
```

It will execute and give me the output. Now I want this job to run every 1 hour. So I do a cronjob

```
     40 * * * * /folder1/scripts/appname/appname.sh
```

The Script appname.sh has

```
    #!/bin/bash

    mvn clean test -Dhr=1 -Dmin=0
```

And it does not work. How can I get this running?

It is an ubuntu machine.

Answer (score -1):

Change the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname "$0")
mvn clean test -Dhr=1 -Dmin=0
```

I inserted a command there to change into the directory where the script is. If your maven project and your script is in the directory `/folder1/scripts/appname/` then this should work.

Withouth this, `cron` executes `/folder1/scripts/appname/appname.sh` from the home directory of the user. Since the project is not there, `mvn clean test` fails.

Instead of changing the script, another alternative is to change the cron job:

```
40 * * * * cd /folder1/scripts/appname && ./appname.sh
```

The point is, one way or another, you need to be in the right directory before running the `mvn` command.